# "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 58-60: truncated \uXXXX escape " error while parsing this string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I am new to python and trying to parse a string using split when i try to parse a log string i am getting the following error

```
  File "main.py", line 1
ans = "2021-08-19 19:13:32,516 :: INFO :: 10.104.220.55 :: config\ucs\manager.py:131 :: Fetching config from live device (can take several minutes)"
     ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 58-60: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

My code is simple:

```
ans = "2021-08-19 19:13:32,516 :: INFO :: 10.104.220.55 :: config\ucs\manager.py:131 :: Fetching config from live device (can take several minutes)"

test = ans.split("::")

print(test)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to use double ```\```.

Comment: `\ ` is an escape character in python. `\u` starts a unicode escape sequence, but really you just wanted to write `\usc`. You can either make a raw string `r"2021-08-19..."` or double backslash to unescape the escape. `\\usc`. This has already been answered here on stackoverflow, so its a duplicate.